# jQuery doesn't work after an Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to sort a list of entries, between `<LI></LI>` tags, and then an Ajax post to validate the order and 'update' the page with the content returned.

```
$.ajax({url: "./test.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&action=modify",
    contenttype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    data: {myJson:  data},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $('html').html(data);
        OnloadFunction ();
        }
    });
```

Then, I lose the ability to sort the list (I'm not sure if clear...). I tried to move the content of the `$(document).ready` inside the `OnloadFunction ()`, and call it with `<script>OnloadFunction ();</script>` inside the block dealing with the modifications to do :

```
$action= $_GET['action'];
if ($action == "modify") {
// Code here
}
```

but it doesn't work...

I can't figure out how to do that. Could anyone help ?

I stripped out the main part of the code to keep only the essential (filename: test.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        //alert("I am ready");
        OnloadFunction ();
        }); 

    function OnloadFunction () {
            $(function() {
            $("#SortColumn ul").sortable({ 
                opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move',
                update: function() {}                                 
                });
            });
            //alert('OnloadFunction ends');
        }

    function valider(){
        var SortedId = new Array(); 
        SortIdNb = 0;
        $('#SortColumn ul li').each(function() {
            SortedId.push(this.id);
        });
            var data = {
            /* Real code contains an array with the <li> id */
            CheckedId: "CheckedId",
            SortedId: SortedId,
            };
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({url: "./test.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&action=modify",
            contenttype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
            data: {myJson:  data},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('html').html(data);
                OnloadFunction ();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?

$action= $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id == 0) {$id=1;}
$id += 1;
if ($action == "modify") {
    echo "action: modify<br>";
    echo "id (àvèc aççént$): ".$id."<br>"; // "(àvèc aççént$)" to check characters because character set is incorrect after the ajax post
    $data = json_decode($_POST['myJson'], true);
    // PHP code here to treat the new list send via the post and update the database
    print_r($data);
    }
?>
<!-- PHP code here to get the following list from the database -->
<div id="SortColumn">
    <ul>
        <li id="recordsArray_1">recordsArray_1</li>
        <li id="recordsArray_2">recordsArray_2</li>
        <li id="recordsArray_3">recordsArray_3</li>
        <li id="recordsArray_4">recordsArray_4</li>
        <li id="recordsArray_5">recordsArray_5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Modifier" onclick="valider();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you replace the full `<html>` element? This will of course get rid of your full Javascript code ... you should reconsider your semantics

Comment: Just a thought, but you are declaring $id after it's called the first time in the ajax url. Also you should only reload the list, not the entire HTML page. i don't quite get what exactly the problem is?

Comment: A good tip is to check for javascript errors in your javascript console, that most browsers have (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/8555)

Comment: This is only a part of the code. The $id is used to call every page, so it is ok. I just modified the code to make it appear on this test page to make sense.
What would you suggest instead of replacing the whole html ? I'm using the page to both treat ($action == "modify") and display the list (once again, I removed the code but the list is displayed from a database, so when I validate, the new list order is recorded and then displayed again)

Comment: The clean way of doing this would be to redirect to the new page instead of replacing the <html> element. The browser will then take care of the rest.

Comment: The redirect is working (when I redirect to the same page, after the update), but I was trying to do it this way...

I edited par of the code above to reflect the data pass through the post.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //alert("I am ready");
    OnloadFunction ();
    }); 

function OnloadFunction () {

        $("#SortColumn ul").sortable({ 
            opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move',
            update: function() {}                                 
            });

        //alert('OnloadFunction ends');
    }
```

Comment: I have an error: TypeError: d is null @ http://potassium:81/intranet/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:3